# How can I place a TextView on top of ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there an easy way to place a TextView on top of ImageView?

My code:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/finaloval"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/greencircleId"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6BNC.png)

The green circle would be my @drawable/finaloval. And the %100 organic would be the TextView.

Comment: Try using a `FrameLayout` as your root

Comment: @juanCruzSoler. I've tried it but it didn't work. Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to set the imageview as the background of the textview.

Do you want to put some words upon a image or a sharp drawable?

I'll use a shape drawable to make an example.

Now I have a shape like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval"
   >

    <size
        android:height="100dp"
        android:width="100dp"
        />

    <solid
        android:color="#66ccff"
        />

</shape>
```

Then set it as the background of a textview in a layout xml.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    />
```

That looks like it. It's a 100dp*100dp one.
[100*100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oziTl.png)

And try to modify the width and height of the textview.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    />
```

Now it looks like this. A Lot Larger.
[200*200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym6LE.png)

So the conclusion is:

- Change the size of drawable and use wrap_content in the layout xml.
- Change "layout_width" and "layout_height" in the layout xml.

But if you want to use the smaller one or the lager one, maybe you should add some control codes in the control java file.

(Sorry I'm not in a English-spoken country so maybe my words is not clear enough)

I'm sorry that I didn't obverse the rules before answer (cuz it's my first answer).

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Thanks but how can I modify the size of the image? I've tried to change the hight and width on the xml file but it did not change the size on the actual main.xml

Comment: @KidM Thanks this worked. I just had to remove the <ImageView from my Xml file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `LinearLayout` as root and re-sequence your views from top to bottom, meaning in your case should be `TextView` then `ImageView`.

**Edited based on comment**

To do overlap of views, you can use `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` as suggested by others.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/finaloval"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/greencircleId"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Think this is the simplest way of doing. Hope this helps

Comment: Can you show me what you mean by "place a TextView on top of ImageView"? A simple drawing of it? @Ali

Comment: Still the Image is on the of the TextView. Anyway, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_versionstatus"  
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"  
                    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/icon_new"  
                    android:text="text"  
                    android:textColor="#363636"  
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

drawableBottom is also a choise for you

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try to set the background for the layout and place your textviews inside that , i have coded it as per the image you shared in it example
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/finaloval">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="100% natural"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:id="@+id/natural"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="organic"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/"
    android:id="@+id/natural"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank this worked. But how can I change the size of the finaloval.xml? I've tried android:hight & android:width but it did not change the size of it.

Comment: Please accept the answer, for changing the oval size try adding padding whether u need space on top ,left bottom or right

Comment: Try adding the width height for relative layout if you have warp content

Answer (score 0):

try this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/finaloval"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/text_black" />
</FrameLayout>
```